# How to add CustomApplication class for log generation android platform?

Tags: android, ionic3

I need to create file having all logcat lines in text file in ionic(3.9.2) project in android platform from installation time.

In native android project we write things in Application class but not getting any idea for ionic.

Also created custom plugin for application, Is it possible to execute method at installation from plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution.

Added custom application class from custom plugin for log file generation.

For manifest entry modify plugin.xml for get all thing working.

I created Application class bellow,

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application{

private static final String TAG = "CustomApplication";

/**
 * Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
 */
public void onCreate() 
{
    Log.e(TAG, "from onCreate");
    super.onCreate();

    if (isExternalStorageWritable())
    {

        Log.e(TAG,"file path : " + this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/MyApp");

        File appDirectory = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/MyApp");
        File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/log");
        File logFile = new File(logDirectory, "logcat" + ".txt");

        // create app folder
        if (!appDirectory.exists())
        {
            appDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        // create log folder
        if (!logDirectory.exists())
        {
            logDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
        try
        {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if (isExternalStorageReadable())
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"only readable external storage");
        // only readable
    } else
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"not accessible external storage");
        // not accessible
    }
}

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable()
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable()
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals( state ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Cordova plugin's plugin.xml file modification for Application as below,

```
<source-file src="src/android/CustomApplication.java" target-dir="src/com/MyApplication" />

<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
    <application android:name="CustomApplication"/>
  </edit-config>
```